# Possible to enable Unlock with Apple Watch, with screen sharing?

Tags: sleep-wake, apple-watch, remote-desktop, unlock

I use a Windows PC as my primary machine, and a 2018 MBP as a secondary "admin" machine for email, etc.  The MBP is right here on my desk, but the ergonomics are such that it is much easier on me physically if I remote-access into the MBP and drive it from my Windows machine/keyboard/mouse.  This works great, with one small but slightly annoying limitation.

I have the machine set to lock after an idle period, and when it locks then a password is required to unlock it.  If I'm not screen sharing, then my Apple Watch (Series 2) unlocks it just fine.  But if I'm connected via my Windows machine, then I have no option but to type the password in.

I really wish the Apple Watch could be allowed to unlock the machine even while screen sharing.  I know this is not a technical limitation, because for some odd reason, if the screen is off WHEN I connect for screen sharing, then it unlocks immediately via the watch.  The "problem" is only if the machine was already connected at the time it goes into display sleep.

Is there any way, via an app or a Terminal command, to override this "feature" of macOS?  I'm running macOS Catalina and Windows 10, using Remote Desktop Manager as the ARD client.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's support page [Unlock your Mac with your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206995) says:

> Also make sure that your Mac isn't using internet sharing or screen
> sharing, which are turned off by default.

So it appears this is a built-in limitation of the unlock feature.

Comment: Understood, but as I pointed out... this capability works PERFECTLY FINE as long as the remote connection is initiated while the machine has gone idle.  So this is clearly not any sort of technical limitation.  The failure to unlock is only a problem if the machine goes into idle while the connection is open, and I wake it from WITHIN that same connection.